# Why does this Shell script fail as cron job

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I have the following in a shell script, when I run this script it works but when I put this as a cron job it does not work(nothing happens!). How come?

**script**

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/home/nalangi/backup.zip"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
   zip -9 -r backupTEMP.zip wso2am-1.7.1;
   rm -r backup.zip;
   mv backupTEMP.zip backup.zip;

else
   zip -9 -r backup.zip wso2am-1.7.1;
fi
```

**crontab entry**

22 14 19 10 0 /home/nalangi/script123.sh

#### UPDATE

The issue turned out to be that the permissions weren't set correctly on the script.

Comment: Prefix your files with paths.

Comment: Also, the recursive switch on rm is superfluous.  A file never needs to be recursively deleted.  I suspect you were trying to troubleshoot the file and tried to remove the r from rf and got as far as deleting the f from rf.  Either way, you shouldn't need either switch.

Comment: When a shell script put in cron fails, what I do is, I modify the crontab script to redirect stderr and stdout to a logfile using the 2>&1. Then I set the cron to the run the next minute and if it fails, i`ll just check the log file to see what is failing or what is wrong. 'cd'ing to the appropriate directory or using full paths to all the files should fix your cron I believe.

Comment: there is no need of trailling semicolon `;` either.

Comment: [Make sure that your local email is configured](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2261/how-are-administrators-supposed-to-read-roots-mail) (it isn't by default in Ubuntu, or at least it used not to be in earlier versions). Cron sends you an email if a job fails or produces any output. If you need further help with this job, tell us what the email from cron contains.

Comment: I redirected the crontab output to a file as Sree suggested and found out that the issue was with the script file not having proper permission. Now it works, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two mistakes in your cron script: First, you should do a `set -e` at the beginning so that any error will end the script immediately. Moreover since you are using relative pathnames, you should do a `cd` to the wanted working directory:

```
cd /home/nalangi
```

**Note.** The cron(8) man page says:

> When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in the crontab, if such exists).

So, if there was an error, you should have got a mail showing the error message.

Comment: Upvote from me here - even though I put in an answer as well.

Comment: @vinc17 are you sure ? I thought cron will change you to `$HOME` dir (which lokks the case here) ?

Comment: @Archemar It seems that the default working directory isn't specified in the cron(8), crontab(1) and crontab(5) man pages. So, you shouldn't assume that it is `$HOME`.

Comment: @vinc17 it depends: in http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab  : Several environment variables are set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon. SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from the /etc/passwd line of the crontab's owner. HOME and SHELL may be overridden by settings in the crontab; LOGNAME may not.

Comment: @Archemar Nothing about the current working directory here (which is not an environment variable, BTW).

Answer (score 0):

I would have implemented it more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, shutil, subprocess

filename = "backup.zip"
home = "/home/nalangi"
tempfile = "backupTEMP.zip"

if os.path.exists(os.path.join(home, filename)):
  subprocess.call(["zip", "-9", "-r", tempfile, "wso2am-1.7.1"])
  os.remove(os.path.join(home, filename)
  shutil.move(os.path.join(home, tempfile), os.path.join(home, filename))
else:
  subprocess.call(["zip", "-9", "-r", filename, "wso2am-1.7.1"])
```